# C# Cast a type to a different type with same declaration

Tags: c#, type-conversion, derived-class

So let's say I have a type `X` which is an abstract class, like so `public abstract class X`. Now let's say i have a type `A` which derives from type `Y`, like this `public class A : Y`. Both `X` and `Y` have the same definition:

```cs
public abstract class X
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }

    public virtual void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }
}

public abstract class Y
{
    public string Name { get; internal set; }

    public virtual void PrintName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }
}
```

I can't change anything inside `X` (Add interface, ...). Also I can not derive from `X` because a program would automatically load it. The classes `X` and `Y` are bigger with fields, properties and a load of methods, but I kept it as minimal, as possible. Is it possible to convert `A` into `X` ? Something like

```cs
X obj = (X)(new A())
```

I have already tried: Json De/Seriliazation, using dynamic `X cls = (X)(new A() as dynamic);`. I probably could use a TypeBuilder, but I don't have any experience using TypeBuilder.

Comment: Is it possible to convert B into A ? means? class or object?

Comment: I guess you want to create an object of type A based on a type B or vice versa?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question, what i want is i have a base class (X), and a class (A) that derives from (Y). I want to convert A to X and pass it into a method.

Comment: Since `X` is abstract you'd need to convert it into something that actually inherits from `X` and is not abstract.

Comment: the thing is, `A` is actually is `DropWeaponPlugin` and `X` is `Plugin`. `Y` is just `Plugin` with different name, so it has the same definition. If `DropWeaponPlugin` derived from `Plugin` it could be turned into `Plugin` using `Plugin plug = (Plugin)new DropWeaponPlugin()`, but the program does that automatically. I dont want it to do it.

Comment: No, you can't "cast" or "convert" one type to another just because they have the same property names. You can _create_ a new object and _copy_ the properties by name, which is what AutoMapper does in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could solve this problem by using AutoMapper:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html

After adding the AutoMapper nuget package to your project, add the following class:

```
public class XYBAProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public XYBAProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Y, X>()
            .Include<A, B>();
        CreateMap<A, B>();
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to create the X object from any A object:

```
 public static void Test()
 {
    var mapperConfig = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(conf => conf.AddProfile<XYBAProfile>());
    var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

    var a = new A() { Name = "Something" };
    X x = mapper.Map<X>(a);

    x.PrintName();
 }
```

Comment: You only need the `A` to `B` map.

Comment: Yeah, and then you can do `B b = mapper.Map<B>(a); X x = b as X;`. It'll raise an error if you try to map directly to X (tried using AutoMapper 9.0).

Comment: Yes, you have to map to `B`, but you don't need the cast, as `X` is a base class.